# cross an htacces with titanium

Tags: php, .htaccess, titanium, titanium-mobile

Here is the problem. i must recover a picture which is generated by a phpfile on my serveur.
the file creeimage.php is in a folder protect by htacess.

i can get this image with firefox .i use this kind of url = http://login:password@www.mywebsite.fr/folderprotectedwithhtaccess/creeimage.php?couleur=violet).

i try this method on titanium but it's not effective:

```
var test= Titanium.UI.createImageView({top:"7%",left:0,width:"100%",height:"31%"});
test.setImage("http://login:password@www.mywebsite.fr/folderprotectedwithhtaccess/creeimage.php?couleur=violet");
```

My question is : do you know how to cross htaccess for my titanium appli to get the picture?
thinqs

the ugly error message on the console :

```
[ERROR][TiDownloadManager( 2372)] (pool-4-thread-1) [13544,13544] Exception downloading http://login:mdp@www.monsite.fr/...
[ERROR][TiDownloadManager( 2372)] java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://login:mdp@www.monsite.fr/...
[ERROR][TiDownloadManager( 2372)]   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
[ERROR][TiDownloadManager( 2372)]   at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
[ERROR][TiDownloadManager( 2372)]   at org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiDownloadManager$DownloadJob.run(TiDownloadManager.java:135)
[ERROR][TiDownloadManager( 2372)]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
[ERROR][TiDownloadManager( 2372)]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
[ERROR][TiDownloadManager( 2372)]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

---

## **EDIT**

---

I made some try : 
if i do

```
http://login:password@www.mywebsite.com/notprotectedbyhtacces/test.png. it works.

http://www.mywebsite.com/protectedhtacces/test.png . it don't work. same error.
http://login:password@www.mywebsite.com/protectedhtacces/test.png . same error .
```

you can change test.png with any phpfile.php?whatyouwantinparam. it's the same.

Comment: I just get a redirect to pagesjaunes fr when accessing that URL

Comment: dear . my real website name is not www.monsite.fr. It was a generic exemple in order to answer for everyone :). sorry i didn't precise this . it's like a put www.mywebsite.fr

Comment: Ah no problem. My French is not so great :)

Answer (score 0):

The URL should have ?couleur=violet (not the &). Perhaps Firefox is "fixing" the URL for you

Comment: unfortunatly not, I misspelled the url in my question.* i edit it*

Answer (score 0):

Looks lile the `libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl` class is saying that it's a bad HTTP request. I'm taking that to mean that it doesn't like the URL with a username and password embedded in the URL. Additionally, make sure your URL returns an actual image and not text/html (which is what I seem to get when I click on it).

Comment: i made some try . the problem don't come from URL unfortunatly :s . i will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

well . I check a lot & contact titanium support. 
the answer seem's to be : it's impossible.

But nothing is impossible!

the best way i found is : 
create a php file in a folder not protected by htaccess.
this file can cross folder protect by htaccess. so it can get an image or whatever you want which is "protect" by htaccess.
the best thinqs to do , in my mind , is to protect execution with a thing like

```
if($_POST[login] == "myloginaccount" && $_POST['password'] == "mypassword"])
{
   do the same things than creeimage.php;
}
else
   throw error;
```

However , there is still a security problem , don't it?

if somebody see a better solution?